# When does a monomorphism must be an automorphism?

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, monomorphisms

Say R is a ring, and denote $\varphi :R\rightarrow R$ a one-to-one homomorphism. Consider the case where $\varphi$ is not onto.

One example is the mapping $(a_{0}, a_{1}, ...) \mapsto (0, a_{0}, a_{1}, ...)$ on $(S^{\mathbb{N}}, \bigoplus, \bigodot)$, the product ring for some arbitrary ring $(S, +, *)$.

Are there any necessary and sufficient conditions on R, for which any monomorphism $\varphi :R\rightarrow R$ is an automorphism?

Comment: A monomorphism of a ring to itself is an automorphism iff it is onto. The example in your second paragraph is not an automorphism since it's not onto (unless $S$ is the trivial ring): consider $(1,1,1,...)$. (Actually, that map isn't even a homomorphism if we're working with *unital* rings, where homomorphisms have to send the multiplicative unit of the source ring to the multiplicative unit of the target ring.)

Comment: I don't know an answer, but here are some examples of rings where every monomorphism is an isomorphism: finite rings, $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q$, and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Forgive me for the silly mistakes. I changed the requirement  in the first paragraph. In general I"m looking for monomorphisms from R to R, which are not onto. Of course your last comment is correct as well.

Comment: The magic word is "co-hopfian". An object $A$ is co-hopfian if every monomorphism $A\to A$ is necessarily an automorphism.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I guess I have a few more subjects to get familiar with..